# how to make a while statement run one more time in python 3

Tags: loops, python-3.x, while-loop, conditional-statements

Is there any way to make a while statement run one more time after it has finished?

- Example:

  ```
  x=1
  while x<=30 :
      print('hello world')
      x+=1
      print(x)
  print('hello world')
  ```

This will obviously print 'hello world' 31 times.
Though in longer programms it is kinda stupid to re-write the whole code again after the loop.

Any help will be appreciated!

UPDATE!
The reason i didnt do x<31 is the following .

I am building a blackjack game.So, when the bank reaches 30$ another round is being played and then the game is over.

bank's value depend's on players betting
(bank strats with 10$ , if player bets 3 and loses the round the bank has 13$)

Comment: How abut making the condition "one more"?

Comment: `This will obviously print 'hello world' 31 times.` <- no it won't. It'll print once for each value between 1 and 29 (inclusive) and once more. So, 30 times

Comment: Is there some reason why changing the while loop to `while x<31:` won't work for you?

Comment: updated a while ago !

Comment: Is there a condition that could cause the while loop to stop prematurely (for example, I'm just such an awesome blackjack player that I bankrupt the bank)?

Comment: yeah if you keep on winning and bet high you will bankrupt the bank :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course, if your condition is numeric, like `x < 30`, you could just change it to `x < 31` or `x <= 30`, but this may not always be possible. Another method would be to wrap the loop body into a function, and call it *within* and once more *after* the loop, but this, too, might not always be practical.

Alternatively, you could use a disjunction of the original condition and some expression that evaluates to `True` the first time, and then to `False`.For example, you could  use an iterator on the list `[True, False]`. As long as the actual condition is `True`, that second part is not evaluated at all (`or` is lazy), then, when the condition is `False`, `next` is called, yielding `True` the first time and then `False`

```
x=1
oncemore = iter([True, False])
while x < 30 or next(oncemore):
    x+=1
    print(x)
```

Or you could defer checking the condition to *inside* the loop. This way, the exit condition will only take effect in the *next* iteration of the loop.

```
once_more = True
while once_more:
    if not (x < 30):
        once_more = False
    # original loop body here
```

Comment: sound interesting i'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

After further editing of the question, this is a fairly straight forward way to do what you want.

EDIT:

```
done = False
x = 1
while not done:
    if x >= 30:
        done = True  # Set done to true once x is greater than or equal to 30
                     # then print one last time
    print('hello world')
    x+=1
    print(x)
```

Instead of this:

```
x = 1
while x < 30:
    print('hello world')
    x += 1
    print(x)
print('hello world')
```

Comment: the loop ends in round 30 and after that there is an extra round.
Actualy i am building a blackjack game. When bank reaches 30$ then another round is being played , but how can i run my code again if while statement stops at 30.

(bank can be 28 and the next round 34 depending on the players betting)

Comment: I'm confused, 30 rounds or $30?

Comment: 30$ .The while loop should end and after that the code should run again for the last time.

Comment: i cound't use the code but my question has been answered!
Thanks for the support though!

Answer (score 0):

I my self prefer else statement with while loop to do it one more time as an example check this out :

```
oncemore = True 
num_list = []
while oncemore:
    num_list.append((num % 10))
    num = int(num / 10)
    if int((num/10)) == 0:
        oncemore = False
else:
    num_list.append((num % 10))
    num = int(num / 10)
    num_list.reverse()
    return num_list
```

after my while loop completely finished else statement do what ever i want one more time just keep this point in your mind while loop should completely finish without any break